# expressJwt: accessing req.user on page that does not require login

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express-jwt, json-web-token

I am using expressJwt (https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) to do my user validation for an angularjs website. I have an interesting situation where I have a URL (/username/somedata) where anyone can access this page. If they are not logged in, or not this user they only get data marked as public. If they are logged in and are the correct user, they get public and private data.

The problem is that you can only access the JWT (json web token) from req.user on any path starting with /api (which requires being logged in)... and since this page does not require login, it doesn't fall under /api.

Is there some way I can allow access to req.user on a path not under /api? Another thought was to check if they are logged in before requesting the data and using a different path...

ie:

not logged in always use:
/username/somedata (always public only data)

is logged in:
/api/username/somedata (check if user is author of data before outputting, if author output public and private ... otherwise only public as well)

UPDATE: I tested the multiple paths and it is working great, but I am still curious if you can access req.user another way, so I am not going to answer my own question just yet.

Comment: See https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/  Why not use the interceptor which intercepts every http packet send from client and attaches JWT (if one exists) to the authorisation header. The JWT is then send with every http request and read by server using **req.headers**. On server only routes with expressJwt middleware require JWT Auth e.g.: app.get('/admin',expressJwt({secret:secret}), getAdmin);

Comment: I do use an interceptor ... but the header data is only set to req.user on urls starting with /api.

Comment: You could attach the JWT to Authorisation Header for ALL http requests to the server. Then to check that a user is logged on correctly before they can access a secure route listen for route changes using  $routeChangeStart. See http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/urls-routing-and-partials/listening-on-route-changes-to-implement-a-login-mechanism.html

Comment: I can't add it to all headers because there is data available when not logged in as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best options, but I use the following:

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');    

var jwtCheck = jwt({
    secret: "secret"
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    jwtCheck(req, res, function() {
        var loggedUserId = _.get(req, 'user.id');
        ...
        //your rest code here
    });
});
```